# Consultas preparadas parametros en SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statements

Estoy optimizando un sistema desde las clásicas consultas mysqli_query() a consultas preparadas y me encontrado con un problema en consultas del tipo:

```
SELECT $campo FROM Tabla WHERE idtabla = $pid
```

Donde $campo es una variable que puede tomar uno u otro nombre de columna dentro de la tabla con mysql_query no tengo problemas para crear dicha consulta, ya que las variables se asignan en el mismo momento de ejecutar la sentencia mediante:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT %s FROM Tabla WHERE idtabla=%s", $campo, $pid);
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error en query.".mysqli_error($conn));
```

Pero con consultas preparadas se requiere que las variables estén definidas antes de crear la consulta, he intentando mediante :

```php
$query = $conn -> prepare ("SELECT ? FROM tabla WHERE idtabla=?");
$query->bind_param('ss', $campo, $pid);

if ($query === false) {
  trigger_error($conn->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  return;
  }
 
if (!$query->execute()) {
echo "Falló la ejecución: (" . $query->errno . ") " . $query->error;
}
else {
     $rs = $query->get_result();
      while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
          $status=$row[$campo];
       }
}
```

Pero al ejecutarla me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: campoN in...

Linea que corresponde a `$status=$row[$campo];`, con lo cual concluyo que el nombre de la variable si pasa, pero no se ejecuta, he intentado una alternativa definiendo una variable string antes de la sentencia preparada mediante :

```php
$smtp = "SELECT $campo FROM tabla WHERE idtabla=".$pid;
```

Y luego con :

```php
$query = $conn -> prepare ($smtp);
```

Se ejecuta correctamente, la duda que me cabe es si esta alternativa es correcta, o con esto anulamos la capa de seguridad de las consultas preparadas; hay alguna alternativa que no sea en base a PDO, ya que el sistema esta diseñado para MySql y no quisiera agregar una capa de abstracción a un sistema que no usará otro motor de base de datos.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: La regla general es que los marcadores de posición `?` sólo se pueden usar donde van valores de columnas; tendrás que usar las técnicas de PHP para variables en cadenas con los valores que no son de columnas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te comentaron, los marcadores de posición son solo para valores, no para columnas, sin embargo, puedes aprovechar que PHP interpreta las variables cuando la cadena está encerrada entre comillas dobles:

```
// Crear la consulta integrando directamente nombre de columna
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT $campo FROM tabla WHERE idtabla=?");
$query->bind_param('s', $pid);
```

Con esto ya debe funcionar como esperas.